# Angular Controller Inheritance and passing parameters

Tags: angularjs, inheritance

I have two controllers one is parent (Base controller) and the second one is child controller, I'm inheriting a the whole parent controller to child controller because the functions in parent controller are same in around 20 controllers.
Inheritance is working fine so far.

**What i'm trying to achieve:**

There is a server function in parent controller which has sourceUrl which is keep changing in every controller, thats the only thing need to be changed when parent controller is inherited and the request is made. now i don't know how to overwrite the sourceURL in parent controller. I think I'll have to use a factory or something. can anyone please help me.

**Parent Controller:**

```
WL_module.controller('WLbaseController', WLbaseController);
    function WLbaseController($scope, $http, $filter, $q, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,  SimpleHttpRequest, serverData)
    {
        $scope.GetTData = function()
        {
            $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions() // make sure to comment it out when working with client side
            .withFnServerData(server) // for server request
            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('stateSave', true) // works only with server side
            .withOption('responsive', true) // not sure if work with both
            .withOption('paging', true)
            .withOption('lengthMenu', [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 100 ])
            .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withButtons([
                'colvis',
                'print',
                'excel'
            ])
            // .withDOM('frtip')
            .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex)
            {
                $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
            });
        };

        function server(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings)
        {
            // Server Request URL
            var sourceUrl = _config.furl+'SelectWL/es_wl_1_11_test';         
            return serverData.request($scope, sourceUrl, sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings); 
        }

        // Always Initialize it to Render the Tables
        $scope.GetTData();
    };
```

**Child Controller:**

```
WL_module.controller('class4_Controller', class4_Controller);
    class4_Controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller', 'DTColumnBuilder', '$filter'];
    function class4_Controller($scope, $controller, DTColumnBuilder, $filter)
    {
        $controller(WLbaseController, {$scope: $scope});

        $scope.dtColumns =
        [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_wl_1_11_test_id').withTitle('W.ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_wl_1_11_test_added_datetime').withTitle('W.A.D')
            .renderWith(function(data, type)
            {
                return $filter('date')(new Date(data), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_wl_1_11_test_edit_datetime').withTitle('W.E.D')
            .renderWith(function(data, type)
            {
                return $filter('date')(new Date(data), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_id').withTitle('O.ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_name').withTitle('O Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_fname').withTitle('O.F.Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_apply_status').withTitle('O Apply Status').notVisible(),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_officer_dob').withTitle('DOB')
            .renderWith(function(data, type)
            {
                return $filter('date')(new Date(data), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
            }),

            // DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_designation_id').withTitle('Desg ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_designation_title').withTitle('Desg Title'),
            // DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_employment_type_id').withTitle('E.T ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_employment_type_name').withTitle('E.T Name'),
            // DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_service_type_id').withTitle('S.T ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_service_type_name').withTitle('S.T Name'),
            // DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_bps_id').withTitle('Bps ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_bps_title').withTitle('Bps Title'),
            // DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_department_id').withTitle('Dept ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_department_name').withTitle('Dept Name'),

            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable().withOption('width', '8%')
            .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta)
            {
                return '<a class="btn btn-success" ng-href="#/Allot_House/' + data.es_officer_id + '">' +
                    '<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Allot' + '</a>';
            })
        ];

        var sourceUrl = _config.furl+'changedURL';
        // I want to override the sourceUrl in server in parent controller with above mentioned sourceUrl 
    };
```

Comment: have you tried inheritance by using service, let A_controller use A_service and B_controller use B_service which extends A_service. use a variable url which is override in child service. so where ever you use B_service you get the overridden url (you can set this value from controller aswel).

Comment: can you give some example also i've read somewhere on stackoverflow that using extend in angular inheritance is not a good idea because it makes a copy. which can mix up the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create inheritance using services than using controller. i have added a sample code .

```
angular.module('app',[])
.service('aService', ['someDependency', function(someDependency){
   this.url = 'a/url';
}])
.service('bService', ['aService', function(aService){
   //you can create a object using aService and return that from service - use this approach when using a factory
   //var bService = Object.create(aService);
   //return bService
   angular.extend(this, aService);
   this.url = 'b/url';
}])
.controller('aCtrl',['$scope','aService', function($scope, aService){
aService.url //gives you 'a/url'
}])
.controller('bCtrl',['$scope','bService', function($scope, bService){
bService.url //gives you 'b/url';
}])
```